# how to have array of paths in swagger?

Tags: javascript, swagger, swagger-ui

I am learning swagger. I am making use of swagger-ui-express package in my node app for documentation. I have more than a file and lot of paths. How can I pass an array to paths property, so that I can minimize code repetition?

My Code :

```
const paths = [
  {
    "/user/my-account": {
      get: {
        responses: {
          "200": {
            description: "Fetched Account successfully",
          },
          "404": {
            description: "No Account was found",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
];

const swaggerConfig = {
  openapi: "3.0.0",
  info: {
    version: "0.0.1",
    title: "Swagger UI",
    description: " Swagger UI",
  },
  servers: [
    {
      url: "http://localhost:4000/",
      description: "Local server",
    },
  ],
  paths: paths.map((path) => {
    return path;
  }),
};

export default swaggerConfig;
```

I need to make this work. How can I?

Comment: Why not process your array into an object that can be used with paths argument? As in object with keys of paths and values as path metadata. Seems like you are almost there. Could probably use array reduce right?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky its not showing in the browser and i am also not sure how to match with the paths property. If you don't mind can you share the code?

Comment: Here is an official json example from the swagger express ui library: https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express/blob/master/test/testapp/swagger.json . Notice that paths is an object not an array. First try changing your array into an object. You can use array reduce with object.entries or object.keys. Show what you try if you continue having issues and then can assist further.

Comment: however i am returning an object only right from mapping

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I don't have idea at all on how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this :

```
let swaggerPaths = {};
const apis = [
  {
    path: "/user/my-account",
    respondWith: {
      get: {
        responses: {
          "200": {
            description: "Fetched Account successfully",
          },
          "404": {
            description: "No Account was found",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    path: "/user/my-account-2",
    respondWith: {
      get: {
        responses: {
          "200": {
            description: "Fetched Account successfully",
          },
          "404": {
            description: "No Account was found",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
];

apis.map((api) => (swaggerPaths[api.path] = api.respondWith));

const swaggerConfig = {
  openapi: "3.0.0",
  info: {
    version: "0.0.1",
    title: "Swagger UI",
    description: "Swagger UI",
  },
  servers: [
    {
      url: "http://localhost:4000/",
      description: "Local server",
    },
  ],
  paths: {...swaggerPaths, /* any other object eg : ...productPaths*/ },
};

export default swaggerConfig;
```

Comment: Wow, btw how can i have multiple objects? like paths : userApi but i need to do like paths: { userApi, productApi} but this is not working